# Forms Pro issue - FormsProFlowApp needs permission to access resources in your organization

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-logic-apps

I receive the following error when I try to add Forms Pro step to logic app

FormsProFlowApp needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it.

AADSTS90094: An administrator of ... has set a policy that prevents you from granting FormsProFlowApp the permissions it is requesting. Contact an administrator of ... who can grant permissions to this application on your behalf.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask admin user add permission for FormsProFlowApp and grant admin consent, then it will work.

You can refer to this tutorial for further information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent

[image]

This post may also helpful to your problem: [How can I find the Admin Consent URL for an Azure AD App that requires Microsoft Graph "Read directory data" permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53309253/how-can-i-find-the-admin-consent-url-for-an-azure-ad-app-that-requires-microsoft)