# MS graph API Oauth2PermissionGrants cannot grant roles

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Using the below code I can approve give admin consent for the first time. 
But when I call the code for the second time. The code returns an error.

**Example:**

I can grant access for `User.Read.All` on the first request.
But when I want to give Admin consent for the second role `AccessReview.Read.All` the request gives below error

**Code**

```
 IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("Client ID")
                .WithClientSecret("Client Secret")
                .WithTenantId("Tenant ID")
                .Build();



            string scopes = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";
            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(app, scopes);
            Beta.GraphServiceClient graphClient = new Beta.GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            Beta.OAuth2PermissionGrant test = new Beta.OAuth2PermissionGrant { ClientId = model.clientId, ConsentType = model.consentType, ExpiryTime = model.expiryTime, ResourceId = model.resourceId, Scope = model.scope };
            var response = await graphClient.Oauth2PermissionGrants
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(test);

            return response.ToString();
```

**Error**

```
Status Code: Conflict
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: Request_MultipleObjectsWithSameKeyValue
Message: Permission entry already exists.
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    request-id: b9e44bc2-7588-4390-a3ca-9abdc213d930
    date: 2020-04-23T19:43:03
ClientRequestId: b9e44bc2-7588-4390-a3ca-9abdc213d930
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. 
Graph API creates a single object for Oauth Grant permission based on consent type. 
Hence for the first request, call the post request to grant the access.
But for the second request update the object using the patch command

```
var oAuth2PermissionGrant = new OAuth2PermissionGrant
{
    Scope = "scope-value"
};

await graphClient.OAuth2Permissiongrants["{id}"]
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(oAuth2PermissionGrant);
```

**Note:**
Add scopes that you have granted access to and which you want to give access in the patch command.
If you add only the scope which you want to give access, then the previous scopes grant access will be revoked and only the new role will have grant access.

Answer (score 2):

You can not add the same permission grant twice, just as the error message said, `permission entry already exists`. If you want to update the permission grant, you can use the update method:

```
var oAuth2PermissionGrant = new OAuth2PermissionGrant
{
    Scope = "scope-value"
};

await graphClient.OAuth2Permissiongrants["{id}"]
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(oAuth2PermissionGrant);
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/oauth2permissiongrant-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Comment: I am not adding same permission twice. I am trying to give consent to new permission. And it gives that error

Comment: @DixonJosephDalmeida How did you give consent to new permission?

Comment: @DixonJosephDalmeida If you call the code you provided, you will add the grant again.

Comment: So i was giving admin consent for User.Read  and then User.Read.All. I thought Graph API creates new object for each admin consent. But it creates only single object per consent type. So I need to patch the as you have told above

Comment: @DixonJosephDalmeida If you just want to give admin consent, you can use Azure portal or build the consent URL. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53310917/10504999

Comment: @DixonJosephDalmeida Also, User.Read doesn't need admin consent.

Comment: Sorry i just gave an example. I know User.read does not need grant permission. Consider any two permissions which need grant permissions

Comment: @DixonJosephDalmeida I see, so do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Comment: No, we are good. Can you add in answer how Oauth objects are created in Azure. When to add and patch. It will help others :-)

Comment: @DixonJosephDalmeida What do you mean of Oauth objects?

Comment: I have added my answer above.